# Git-Moving an older commit to tip of master

Tags: git, azure-devops

We merge all changes in master and it needs to be a PR. All release strictly happens from master. We are not allowed to release from any other branch. We don't release each and every commit instead once in a sprint (2 weeks) after testing the release candidate (commit). The problem is once we release we don't stop our active line of development and in case we need to give a hotfix later we have to fork out from a released commit to another branch. This demands a release from a hotfix branch. Unfortunately, we have a policy of release only from master. Is there a way we can move the release commit to tip of the master and provide the fixes and release from master. Later we want to integrate everything which happened after release back to master.

Is there a way to achieve this without stopping main line of development and violating release from master policy?

Comment: No, there isn't, not without rewriting history and that won't sit well with your PRs. You should google for git-flow and change your "only release from master" rule to something that actually works.

Comment: Isolate in-progress feature work behind feature toggles so you can keep `master` in an always-shippable state.

Comment: You workflow seems ok. After the work on `hotfix` branch, you can merge `hotfix` branch into `master` and then create a new release for the changes merged into `master`. So what's your cencer here?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Releasing hotfix is not happening from Master

Comment: @ShijuSamuel You can do the release **after** `hotfix` merged into `master` branch. And for verify the changes on hotfix branch, you can use build validation policy in PR, or you can verify the hotfix in a separate build/release definition.

Comment: @ShijuSamuel Does the workflow to release after merging go smoothly, or do you solve the problem with a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to point `master` at another commit in the past? Sure. First, make sure your current `master` branch won't be deleted by putting it on a new branch.

```
git checkout -b old-master
```

Then switch back to `master`

```
git checkout master
```

Now, force master back to whatever previous commit you want

```
git reset --hard 0eaf3276
```

Alternately, if you have the release tagged, you can use that.

```
git reset --hard v1.0.0
```

Now, if you want to push your new master branch up, just do

```
git push --force
```

Also, your "only release from master" policy is dumb. But you probably already know that. :D

Comment: I agree, the problem is not technical